# How do you deal with dual drives (partitions) on linux computers?

Tags: partition, disk, pop-os

I've been surprised by how difficult it has been to manage a linux PC with the OS on its own partition, and I'd be very curious to hear other peoples strategies and ideas.

**Background**

A couple of years ago, I bought a great gaming computer for my son from System76.  It comes with Pop_OS.  Upon ordering, I choose  divided the drive into an OS partition and another bigger partition for data.  The argument for doing so is very compelling.  It goes like this:

> If there a disk failure, the OS is less likely to be affected if you put the OS on its own partition.  Thus you're less likely to have catastrophic failures of your system.

Now, I'm constantly having to intervene with the system, because EVERYTHING attempts to use the OS partition instead of the data partition.

After much struggle and several tutorials, I've decided it's too difficult to move minecraft to the other partition.

I did manage to get Steam to start installing new games onto the data partition.

For Videos (my son is learning to do screen casts),  I've created a symbolic link to a directory inside of ~/Videos.  And I've instruction my son to save files to ~/Videos/MyVideos instead of just ~/Videos.

What's everybody else doing?

My solutions seem difficult and clunky.  But I thought separating out your OS was a pretty common thing, so I can't be the only one facing such issues.

I'd be happy to hear any thoughts.

Comment: Some questions: you are not using LVM, correct? Why do you think a drive failure will not effect all partitions on said drive, or do less harm to the OS? The only scenario I can imagine is a filesystem corruption. It might help to include the output of `mount` and `df -h` in your question.

Comment: It sounds like you really just want to mount the "data" partition on `/home` (but you'll have to copy the existing homedir contents over first).

Answer (score 1):

Your options to control which physical storage (partition etc.) is used for a logical purpose (like recording or editing videos) are

1. Find out what path your software expects to use, and mount the desired partition on that path.

   Just mounting your storage partition on `/home` (after copying your existing user homedir contents) works for all applications, all file types, etc.

   Mounting it on `~/Video` works for all applications which use that directory, although you can mount the same storage on as many filesystem paths as you want.
2. Find out what path your software expects and make *that path* a symlink to the desired storage, wherever it is mounted
3. Tell your software to use a different path using standard [XDG config](https://superuser.com/a/1785798)
4. Configure each individual software package in its own idiosyncratic way

in order of decreasing generality.

The XDG config works for all properly-written desktop applications - which *may* not be all of them - and doesn't require root or sudo to set up mounts. I'd start there and only go "more general" if you really need to.

Comment: Thank you.  This is great.